# How to include quotes(") into a string used by HTTP Head fields in Swift

Tags: swift, http, github

Recently I used the **GitHub API** to request some resources, I found **Etag** would help me since it could avoid duplicate URL requests. However, I met a problem with HTTP request with ETag included.

According to ETag(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), if you want to compare previous Etag with current URL request result, you should send that information within HTTP Header, the key value pair that included in a HTTP Header Field should have the form like this

```
 If-None-Match: "686897696a7c876b7e"
```

From the above observation, if I got an Etag like this

```
 Etag = "W/\"e1a6465809efe351293dd5bda041a795\""
```

I should save the part **e1a6465809efe351293dd5bda041a795**

I then use two kind of code in **swift** to do a URL request

### The First Method (with quotes included)

```
// components[1]:String = "e1a6465809efe351293dd5bda041a795"
request.setValue("\"\(components[1])\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
```

### The Second Method (without quotes included)

```
// components[1]:String = "e1a6465809efe351293dd5bda041a795"
request.setValue("\(components[1])", forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
```

Both of them couldn't work even if **Etag** hasn't changed.

The result like this:

```
status code: 200, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" = "ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval";
"Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Security-Policy" = "default-src 'none'";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 07 Jul 2015 00:46:53 GMT";
Etag = "W/\"e1a6465809efe351293dd5bda041a795\"";
```

I am very confused.

If **Etag** remains the same, the response status should be 304, however every time I request I will get a 200, even if the result has no change.

I think the problem may be caused by the quote representation in swift, any one could help me?

## Note

The problem is at my github repo [GitPocket](https://github.com/jindulys/GitPocket), hope someone could help me directly in the repo!! you could find the problem by *ctrl + F* **problem here**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying with Alamofire, I was able to fix it. I used following request

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jindulys/received_events")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

//let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
mutableURLRequest.setValue("\"ae651e23bd54274b1c046e7b804feeb7\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")

return Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
```

I think the problem only exist in iOS 9.0, I think it is the iOS 9.0 SDK problem.